# How to make second column as a auto increment after creating first column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I just want to produce primary key with auto increment column in mysql table

Tried:
customer_id(PK, AI)      first_name    last_name    balance

1                          prawin        kumar       1000
2                          sunny         leone       1000000
3                          emily         clarke      10000

Expected:
customer_id(PK, AI)      first_name    last_name    balance

00001              prawin        kumar               1000
00002              sunny         leone              1000000
00003              emily         clarke              10000

PK - Primary key , AI - Auto Increment

Comment: Is customer_id an int datatype?  if so you cannot store padded , Why do you wish to do so? LPAD on query may be sufficient for your purposes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `ZEROFILL`

```
CREATE TABLE `sampledb`.`yourtable` (
    `customer_id` INTEGER(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    `balance` INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
);
```

Input (Insert) :

```
INSERT INTO `sampledb`.`yourtable` (`customer_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `balance`) VALUES ('1', 'prawin', 'kumar', '1000');
INSERT INTO `sampledb`.`yourtable` (`customer_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `balance`) VALUES ('2', 'sunny', 'leone', '1000000 ');
INSERT INTO `sampledb`.`yourtable` (`customer_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `balance`) VALUES ('3', 'emily', 'clarke ', '10000');
```

Output :

```
select * from yourtable;
```

[image]

Comment: 'As of MySQL 8.0.17, the ZEROFILL attribute is deprecated for numeric data types...You should expect support for ZEROFILL and display widths for integer data types to be removed in a future version of MySQL.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html